# Win32 API analog of sending/catching SIGTERM

Tags: windows, winapi, posix, shutdown, sigterm

Under POSIX OS there is signal API that allows to send a signal to process to shut it down
with kill and you can catch it with sigaction and do what you need;

However, Win32 is not POSIX system, so:

- How can I handle shutdown events that may come, for example from "End Process" in "Task manager"?
- What is the standard API for sending shutdown signal to Win32 application?

I'm not talking about GUI, I'm talking about TCP/IP server that should be nicely shutdown. that **does not** run like windows service.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a `WM_QUIT` message on your first created thread.

When you don't handle that, your process is forcibly shutdown.

So just implement a message queue in your first thread, which looks for the `WM_QUIT` message

Comment: You should handle WM_CLOSE. "The WM_QUIT message is not associated with a window and therefore will never be received through a window's window procedure. It is retrieved only by the GetMessage or PeekMessage functions." -MSDN

Comment: Can I use same method for Console Ctrl+C and for process runnig as Windows service? Or I should use different methods for each one of them?

Comment: You can use **taskkill /im your_program.exe** to send a termination signal to the application. It will trigger a **WM_CLOSE** in windows message queue as @Indy9000 mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

MSDNs ***Unix Code Migration Guide*** has a chapter about [Win32 code conversion and signal handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms811896(v=msdn.10)#signals-and-signal-handling).
Although Microsoft has decided to archive this brilliant guide, it is very useful.

Three methods are described:
Native signals
Event objects
Messages

Answer (score 4):

May be Windows Power Management from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968807(VS.85).aspx) would be helpful. But it deals with system events rather than per process.

For a process, you would be able to detect termination with `WM_CLOSE`. You would need to handle windows messages. If it's a console application you would need to install a control handler; take a look at [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN