# Execute a process or Create a process and set time interval to closed it

Tags: delphi, winapi, createprocess

I would like to execute an application with parameters without a gui window, then auto end process gracefully in 2minutes.

This is how I use the code:

```
procedure ExecNoWait(Filename: string);
var
   bchExec: array[0..1024] of char;
   pchEXEC: Pchar;
   si: TStartupInfo;
   pi: TProcessInformation;
begin
   pchExec := @bchExec;
   StrPCopy(pchExec,Filename);
   FillChar(si,sizeof(si),0);
   FillChar(pi,sizeof(pi),0);
   si.dwFlags:=STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
   si.wShowWindow:=SW_HIDE;
   si.cb := sizeof(si);
   CreateProcess(Nil,pchExec,Nil,Nil,false,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, Nil,Nil,si,pi);
end;


ExecNoWait(TheExeFilePath + '\ThisExe.exe -runnow'); //NON-GUI App
```

But I want to auto end or auto close the ThisExe.exe gracefully in 2minutes time.

How do we solved this?

thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as *graceful termination* of a process. Terminating a process is always rude, and with extreme prejudice.

Comment: Probably your best option would be to post `WM_CLOSE` or `WM_QUIT` to the process and hope it handles those messages properly. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055753/how-to-gracefully-terminate-a-process

Comment: @MarkoPaunovic: The app being run has no GUI, though, so no window to post messages to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that depends. CMD.EXE reports to closing window and every console app should respond to Windows Shutdown/Reboot alert. So it boils down to the question if controlled application is buggy or correct

Comment: Do you have control over ThisExe application? Just add into it any means of IPC (interprocess communications) so it could receive shutdown request and close itself.

Comment: @XenKid Graceful termination involves co-operation. What mechanism does the other process offer for graceful termination?

Answer (score 3):

`CreateProcess()` returns a `THandle` to the new process in the `TProcessInformation` record.  You can pass that handle to `WaitForSingleObject()` with a 2-minute timeout. If the timeout elapses, you can then pass the same handle to `TerminateProcess()` (since there is no GUI involved, there is no option for a "graceful" termination), eg:

```
var
  bchExec: string;
  si: TStartupInfo;
  pi: TProcessInformation;
begin
  bchExec := Filename;
  UniqueString(bchExec);
  FillChar(si, sizeof(si), 0);
  FillChar(pi, sizeof(pi), 0);
  si.cb := sizeof(si);
  si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  si.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(bchExec), nil, nil, false, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, si, pi) then
  begin
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    if WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 120000) = WAIT_TIMEOUT then
      TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 666);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: So does CMD have GUI or not? It can be closed gracefully. And what about Windows Services that mostly are GUI - less?

Comment: @Arioch'The CMD has a close button, but using it is not equivalent to gracefully closing, the running program is aborted. Windows Services should handle the close command and can be stopped gracefully.

Comment: Windows services are controlled by the SCM. Use the SCM API, not `CreateProcess()`, to interact with services. Look at [`StartService()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686321.aspx) and [`ControlService()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108.aspx) and other related functions.

Comment: @The_Fox I am not asking about running programs, but about CMD itself. You can run CMD-script and when you would click that button, CMD would gracefully ask to cancel script execution. Also I think programs like FAR and nFTP and other console-targeted would also react to close and close in a proper manner.

Comment: @RemyLebeau what does it change in the global claim that any program w/o GUI cannot be closed gracefully ? It only is a matter of communication implemented at BOTH sides. GUI program can also be buggy and ignore close requests just like text-UI one. But that does not mean GUI programs cannot be closed gracefully in general, it only means one particular program is buggy.

Comment: GUI apps are designed to be closed gracefully - issue a `WM_QUIT` message to each window to break out of their message loops. Closing the console window forces all console processes to terminate, after a Ctrl+Close notification is first sent to them so they can clean themselves up. Ctrl+Close cannot be aborted, unlike Ctrl-C and Ctrl+Break, which can.

Comment: Very good experts here, but I'm still confused, I'll get back for more testing. thanks