# C++ Windows Program Detecting Program Exit | No GUI or console

Tags: c++, winapi

In my C++ Windows Program without a console or GUI I wan't to detect if the task is being cancelled/stopped.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

How does your "task" run and how is it stopped? If it's just killed/terminated from the outside, then you can't detect it inside that process.

If your program exits in a regular fashion (no kill, no quick exit), you can register a "cleanup" function with [atexit()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit), which will be run during exit().

EDIT: Or since it's C++, you could use a global variable with a custom type and run your code inside the destructor, which is basically the same as atexit().

Answer (score 3):

`atexit()` would be the C-portable way to do it.

If you want to use a Windows specific way to do it, see this: [Win32 API analog of sending/catching SIGTERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216788/win32-api-analog-of-sending-catching-sigterm)