# How to execute code just before terminating the process in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

This question concerns multiprocessing in python. I want to execute some code when I terminate the process, to be more specific just before it will be terminated. I'm looking for a solution which works as [`atexit.register`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#atexit.register) for the python program.

I have a method worker which looks:

```py
def worker():
    while True:
        print('work')
        time.sleep(2)
    return
```

I run it by:

```py
proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=())
proc.start()
```

My goal is to execute some extra code just before terminating it, which I do by:

```py
proc.terminate()
```

Comment: There is no way to do that since `process.terminate()` asks the operating system to kill with `SIGTERM`. So no `finally` handlers etc. will be executed.

Comment: You can provide a `SIGTERM` signal handler. See `signal.signal` in https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/signal.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use signal handling and intercept SIGTERM:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys
from signal import signal, SIGTERM

def before_exit(*args):
    print('Hello')
    sys.exit(0)  # don't forget to exit!


def worker():
    signal(SIGTERM, before_exit)
    time.sleep(10)

proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=())
proc.start()
time.sleep(3)
proc.terminate()
```

Produces the desirable output just before subprocess termination.

Comment: Note that this will not work on Windows

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1216788