# Python: Catch the failure of a try

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to understand why a "try" command from a subprocess is failing but I can't get to the error. I need a bit of help as I can't figure out how the subprocess and the try/except method work.

In details, I have a main.py function which creates a subprocess:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import...
    
# Create subprocess
subprocess = Popen(['python3','~/test.py'],stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

My file test.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import...

try:
   code to execute if all good
except:
   code to execute if exception
```

When I run main.py, the subprocess test.py is created and executed but sometimes fails and the code under except is not even executed. Is there a way to access to the output of the code in the section try to understand where the issue is?

EDIT: test.py is a subprocess which runs continously along with main.py

Comment: To clarify, is `main.py` or `test.py` the script that is failing? Are you expecting to catch an exception that was raised in different process?

Comment: `test.py` might get killed before any exception handling. You can try to catch some signals https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560706/how-to-execute-code-just-before-terminating-the-process-in-python

Comment: @Brian This is the code `code to execute if all good` in `test.py` which fails and I'm not working with other process. `Test.py` is the subprocess which fails and I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: How exactly do you know that the code in try-block fails and the code in except-block isn't executed?

Comment: @MichaelButscher My mistake, there was an issue in my code. The except-block is indeed executed.

Comment: A precision. My problem is really when I execute `test.py` even by self. I know an exception is raised in the try-block since the execute goes to the except-block but I don't know where. Is there a was to know that?

Comment: The "traceback" module can help. E. g. "traceback.print_exc()" in the except-block prints the full traceback of exception that caused the execution of the except-block.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. Now, I just need to find a way to write the output of this command to a file or send it back to the parent-process