# How do I detect if the CLI PHP process/window is closed with the "X" button?

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface, cross-platform

I'm trying to handle the very common event of somebody closing a running PHP CLI terminal window by clicking its "X" button or by "killing" it from the command line with "taskkill".

By "handle", I mean "I want this quick but important function of mine to run before it ends".

I currently use `register_shutdown_function()`, which *sounds* like it would be perfect for this. However, in my tests, the function set by `register_shutdown_function()` is NOT called when the window is closed or the process is killed by other means, nor when `Ctrl + C` is pressed while it's running. It *only* is run when the script exited/ended on its own.

`sapi_windows_set_ctrl_handler()` *does* execute when Ctrl + C is pressed, but not when the window is closed, which is by far the most important and common way my PHP CLI processes are "unexpectedly" closed.

The `pcntl_*` functions cannot be used since they are Linux-only, while all my PHP code needs to be cross-platform.

Specs: *PHP 7.4.10* on *Windows 10 Pro 2004*.

Comment: NT doesn't provide the notion of a graceful SIGTERM. And PHP, being a commandline tool, won't receive any [WM_QUIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216788/win32-api-analog-of-sending-catching-sigterm) from Windows.

Comment: What window do you mean? The terminal? Or did you use any kind of GUI like GTK or QT?

Comment: @mario Well... Thanks, but how do I actually solve it?

Comment: @MarkusZeller As mentioned, "PHP CLI terminal window".

Comment: The short answer is: you probably can't.

Comment: @mario But... Then everything I've worked on falls apart in the last fine-tuning stages... Please tell me there is a way. This can't be.

Comment: Maybe you could try a workaround by using Docker.